# need help understanding this python code snippet

Tags: python

I came across the following in an online python test:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for a[3] in a:
    print a[3]
```

When i plug it into the interpreter (python 2.7) I get:

```
0
1
2
2
```

I can't for the life of me make out why this behaves the way it does.  Can someone please explain?

Comment: You're replacing `a[3]` with each iteration of the loop. Have a look with e.g. http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: It's resetting the 4th item in the list on each iteration and ultimately it is just bad code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It puts elements of a to a[3] and prints it. When it comes to the fourth element, it puts a[3] to itself, but it has a[3] = 2 because of the previous iteration. In some sense it is similar to:

```
for x in a:
    a[3] = x
    print a[3]
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.